# problemas con JSONObject al hacer peticion

Tags: php, android-studio

estoy creando una app pero en un layout de registro estoy tratando de hacer que e almacene datos en una base de datos BD al querer hacerlo y ejecutar la app en el metodo de el boton que guarda todos esos datos en un archivo php para asi mismo mandarlos a la BD me marca este error al debuguear

y aqui "Response.Listener respoListener = new Response.Listener() {"
" JSONObject jsonResponse =  new JSONObject(response);"
al revisar el debug

"
en este error al observar el debug dice esto
"06-27 11:51:13.647 18179-18179/com.example.igo W/System.err:     at com.example.igo.nuevousuario$1.onResponse(nuevousuario.java:62)
06-27 11:51:13.647 18179-18179/com.example.igo W/System.err:     at com.example.igo.nuevousuario$1.onResponse(nuevousuario.java:55)"

creen poder ayudarme con ideas por favor!!!y doy gracias a los que se toman el timpo de ante mano

```
package com.example.igo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.gms.common.util.Strings;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import static android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

public class nuevousuario extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText celN,nombreN,apPaternoN,apMaternoN,emailN,passwordN;
    Button btn_registrar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nuevousuario);
//--------VARIABLES YA NO HAY CAST POR ANDROIDX ---------------
        nombreN =  findViewById(R.id.nombre_NuevoU);
        apPaternoN =  findViewById(R.id.ap_paterno_nuevoU);
        apMaternoN =  findViewById(R.id.ap_materno_nuevoU);
        emailN = findViewById(R.id.correo_NuevoU);
        passwordN = findViewById(R.id.contraseña_NuevoU);
        celN = findViewById(R.id.cel_nuevoU);
        //------BOTON DE REGISTRO--------------
        btn_registrar = findViewById(R.id.crear_nuevo_usuario);
        btn_registrar.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
//-------------EVENTO ONCLICK DEL BOTON REGISTRAR------------
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        final String nombre=nombreN.getText().toString();
        final String apellido_paterno=apPaternoN.getText().toString();
        final String apellido_materno=apMaternoN.getText().toString();
        final String email=emailN.getText().toString();
        final String password=passwordN.getText().toString();
        final String celular=celN.getText().toString();

        /**/ Response.Listener<String> respoListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {

                   /**/ JSONObject jsonResponse =  new JSONObject(response);


                    boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");


                    if(success){
                        Intent intent =  new Intent(nuevousuario.this,MainActivity.class);
                        nuevousuario.this.startActivity(intent);

                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (), "no se hizo el registro" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show ();
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(nuevousuario.this);
                        builder.setMessage("No se ha podido registrar el usuario")
                                .setNegativeButton("Regresar",null)
                                .create().show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };

        regitrorequest regitrorequest= new regitrorequest(nombre,apellido_paterno,apellido_materno,email,password,celular,respoListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(nuevousuario.this);
        queue.add(regitrorequest);








    }
}"
```

Este es mi archivo en php
"

```
mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","Bd_local_usuarios");


$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$apellido_paterno = $_POST["apellido_paterno"];
$apellido_materno = $_POST["apellido_materno"];
$email =  $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$celular = $_POST["celular"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con,"INSERT INTO _clientes_taxis(nombre,apellido_paterno,apellido_materno,email,password,celular) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement ,"ssssss",$nombre,$apellido_paterno,$apellido_materno,$email,$password,$celular);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array(
'nombre' => $nombre,
'apellido_paterno' => $apellido_paterno,
'email' => $email,
'password' => $password,
'celular' => $celular);
$response ["success"] = true;

echo json_encode($response, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

?>
"

Comment: puedes hacer un Log.i(response) para ver que lleva la respuesta del servidor

Comment: gracias lo provare @IgmerRodriguez